# why spf soft fail appear hard fail in gmail

Tags: linux, sendmail, spf

abc.com.   1D IN TXT    "v=spf1 a mx   ipv4:10.11.x.x -all"
This is result i got using dig
root#dig txt abc.com.

But when i send mail to my gmail from this domain, gmail says softfail and 10.11.x.x is not allowed to send mail for this mail.

Can anyone please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo - `ipv4` instead of `ip4`

Comment: Alex is absolutely right: see the standard definition at eg http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax for more details.

Comment: I did , no luck some domains still appearing in soft fail while configured for hard fail

Comment: Try adding prefix-length to IP, e.g. 10.11.x.x/16